# Element can be located with getElementById, but can't assign it to a variable

Tags: getelementbyid

See the console result below.  Why is it that I can find the element with getElementById, but when I try to assign the element to a variable, I get "undefined"?  I have searched for an answer but can't find anything.

[Javascript Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaJ7m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `undefined` is result of your declaration expression. Not the value of your variable `boo`.

Try type `boo` in console, it will output same as `document.getElementById("close")`.